# Cannot pass arguments from URL to REST server

Tags: go, restful-url

I'm trying to create a client server REST application.

Below is a part of the server which listens on port 8080.

With "create" function I created a new room, added that room to roomArray and notify client that the room was created.

clientName is a random string generator which will be generated in a function.

```
var member *Client//global variable
type Client struct {
    currentRoom *Room
    outputChannel chan string
    name string
}

///

func main() {
       router := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(true)
       router.HandleFunc("/", CreateClient).Methods("GET")     
       router.HandleFunc("/rooms/{ROOMNAME}", create).Methods("POST")

       http.ListenAndServe(":8080", router)
}

func create(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    roomName := mux.Vars(r)["ROOMNAME"]
    clientName := r.Header.Get("username") // It'll take it from a random string generator function
    for _, cli := range Members{
        if cli.name == clientName{
            member = cli
        }
    }
    // Is the name unique?
    for _, room := range RoomArray {
        if roomName == room.name {
            member.outputChannel <- "The room name you have specified is already in use\n"
            return
        }
    }
    newRoom := &Room{
        name: roomName,
        clientList: make([]*Client, 0), // room will start empty, we wont add the creator in
        previousMSG: nil,
    }
    RoomArray = append(RoomArray, newRoom)
    if newRoom == nil { // not unique
        return
    }
    member.outputChannel <- client.name+" created a new room called "+roomName + "\n"
}
```

I also created another function named listrooms, that I can check created rooms.

After running server, I type http://localhost:8080/rooms/go in the browser. I'm passing "go" as roomName.

My problem is that, "create" function does not work so, I don't get any result. I don't even get any errors.

When I check list of rooms, it's empty thus no rooms were created.

Everything works fine in terminal but I want to be able to create a room from browser.

Can someone check the code below to tell me my mistakes, please?

Comment: What is the intended purpose of `outputChannel`? You don't show the code or explain how that channel is being read... you have to understand that a channel that is not being read from properly could block indefinitely (e.g. https://play.golang.org/p/kgHPI5cbb30).

Comment: Why is `member` a global? Most, if not all, of Go's http servers, including gorilla, are concurrent by default, meaning that `create` can easily be executed by multiple goroutines at the same time which will cause a data race on you global variables if you don't use some sort of synchronization, like a mutex for example.

Comment: There seems to be no point in the last `if` statement of the `create` handler. If the room is not unique you already return from the above loop.